# How to build a query in mongodb and execute like sql

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongodb driver in c#.
I can create query for CRUD operations sqlserver in c# . But i need to Create query for mongodb and execute it .
For an sample i attached Delete
**Delete Query**

```
string query = string.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1}"
```

ExecuteNonquery method i can execute it in sqlConnection

How i do this in mongodb?

Comment: [MongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/). Read it. Also don't spam tags just to get attention.

Answer (score 1):

You should see [FilterDefinitionBuilder TDocument](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1.htm) which provides a type-safe API for building up both simple and complex MongoDB queries.

For example to build up the filter `{ x: 10, y: { $lt: 20 } }`, you can use below:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("x", 10) & builder.Lt("y", 20);
```

You can see more examples on mongo-csharp-driver tests for [FilterDefinitionBuilder](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/FilterDefinitionBuilderTests.cs) class.